# how to make tshark executable

Tags: wireshark, gcc-warning, strict-aliasing, tshark

After downloading and extracting wireshark 1.7.1, I did a configure with gtk disabled.
But then , I am unable to do "make" 
It throws the following error.

cc1: warnings being treated as errors
packet-h248_annex_e.c:679: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules.

Can someone help with building and installing this wireshark version ?

Comment: Why don't you try the last version (1.8.3)?

Comment: Actually I need this specific version

Comment: What about configuring the standard way, building everything and just using tshark. It should not rely on GTK.

Comment: Can you provide link to sources, or svn revision number you are trying?

Comment: http://www.filehippo.com/download_wireshark_32/12050/

Comment: Discribe your system and how do you configure and build wireshark, pls.

Comment: I have got Linux 2.6.23.1-42.fc8 and i configured using ./configure --disable-wireshark --disable-gtk2 --disable-editcap --disable-idl2wrs --disable-ipv6 --enable-setuid-install

This part is going through properly. After this, on make errors are thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like developers left some warnings in this build. Try to configure with --disable-warninngs-as-errors.